# How to work with branches in XCode (SVN)

Tags: xcode, svn, branch

I successfully set up SVN and XCode, it's really cool !
I commit, update, I even tag (in the Terminal though...) ! All this is pretty easy
Now I'd like to work with different branches, but I'm a bit confused.

I'v followed [this tutorial](http://repeatgeek.com/tools/using-subversion-with-xcode-part-iii/), and it has a section about branching. What it says is to use this script :

```
#!/bin/ksh
# A script to branch a SVN trunk
reporoot=/Library/Subversion/Repository/
projdir=Projects

# Prompt for repository name
print -n "Enter repository name:"
read repo

# Prompt for project name
print -n "Enter project name:"
read project

# Prompt for branch name
print -n "Enter branch name:"
read branch

# Create branch
svn copy file://$reporoot/$repo/$projdir/$project/trunk file://$reporoot/$repo/$projdir/$project/branches/$branch -m "Creating a branch of the ‘$project‘ project."

echo
echo Creation of a branch of the $project project complete!
echo
```

But what I see is it's just a shell script that copies the current trunk to a branch (like a tag). And so if I do this, I will still be committing in the trunk no ?

Do you have any idea of a way to be able to "switch" easily between branches, for updates and commit ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would love to be able to do this too. How can you switch to a branch, either within or outside Xcode? Surely the whole point of version control is to be able to view different branches or versions of your project within the same Xcode project? This seems difficult to achieve with branches. It's also seems to be impossible to compare one branch with another branch, although I think that's built into SVN itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subversion doesn't have a branch system. This is why you usually see a folder with "trunk", "tags" and "branches" in it. If you want to be able to switch between branches and the trunk effectively, you would probably have to create a symlink to the branch you are using. If you later wish to switch branches, you simply re-create this symlink.

I am not sure whether Xcode likes this though, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try XCode 4, it allows to create branches, switch and merge them in full mode, not the way XCode 3 used to do it.

UPDATED: You should use **svn switch** after you create your new branch. It will update you working copy.

Example:

```
svn switch http://slitvinov@192.168.1.117:8080/svn/alb.iphone/Branches/SuperFastAlgo
```

Full description is [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html)

Comment: It's nice to know that XCode 4 does a better job than XCode 3 ! But We can not switch yet, since Google Toolbox for Mac doesn't support XCode 4

Answer (score 1):

I would use Git over SVN and use GitX. You'll have a much easier time working with branches, especially if you want to use them practically and not spend half an hour on merges. The XCode3 SCM integration isn't particularly full-featured. If at all possible, I'd try XCode4 with Git, and clone and add vendor libraries as submodules. (This is all somewhat SOP as of 2012).

You can always use `git svn` commands ([sample tutorial](http://viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion)).

There's also an [Objective-C .gitignore Github project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore). Having the Git repo only physically in the project root also is a big plus.

Comment: I eventually dropped SVN, and use GIT. It's what everybody recommends, and they're right!